# Dynamic Array with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Post Updated

I would like to create dynamic Array in PHP to provide the same output like static Array below, I have tried to do it with while statement but it doesn't work. Could you please provide me some tips?

I would like to use 2 values from MySQL and save them in to $to variable
so first send_to1 (user account) and then value1 (amount)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");

$to=Array(

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

$send_to1 => $value1,
$send_to2=> $value2
  }

);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `$to[$send_toX] = $valueX;` ?

Comment: Arrays in PHP are always dynamic in every imaginable aspect. Describe what ooperation you would like to perform on an array!

Comment: Change `$new_array[] = $row[]` to `$new_array[] = $row` `$row` is already an array

Comment: replace `print_r($new_array[] = $row[]);` with `$new_array[] = $row;`

Comment: `$to[] = array('val1' => $row['val1'], 'val2' => $row['val2']);`

Comment: @user2511459 `$to[$i]['valx'] = $row['valx'];` ... but you need a counter here, or an `id` at least ...

Comment: @user2511459 You can make an `array` within a `loop`, but you can not put a `loop` inside an `array` ... see my answer BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, this is so easy, you just need to pay more attention to the answers you're getting here.

Here is the simplest way you can do it:

```
$to = array();
$to[] = array($send_to1 => $value1);
$to[] = array($send_to2 => $value2);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $to[] = array($row['send_tox' => $row['valuex']);
}
```

You need to first understand how *Arrays* and *Loops* work in PHP, then try to make a dynamic array in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as just adding elements to the array:

```
//Setup blank array
$example = array();

//Create a loop, for example purposes.
foreach(range(0, 99) as $i){

    //Create random variable that we'll add to our array
    $randVar = mt_rand(1, 90000);

    //$i will be our array key/index
    $example[$i] = randVar;

}

//var_dump the array so you can see the structure / end result
var_dump($example);
```

You could also create it like so:

```
//Create random array key/index
$myRandKey = mt_rand(1, 90000);

//Create random variable value.
$myRandVar = mt_rand(1, 90000);

//Setup an array
$example = array(
    $myRandKey => $myRandVar
);

//Another array key that we'll add to our array
$secondKey = 'test';

//Add it
$example[$secondKey] = 'This is just an example!';

//Dump out the array
var_dump($example);
```

array_push will also work (using mysql_fetch_assoc, like in your example):

```
$example = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($example, $row);
}
var_dump($example);
```

In your particular example (since you added your code):

```
print_r($new_array[] = $row[]);
```

should be changed to:

```
print_r($new_array[] = $row);
```

In your code, I'd change it to:

```
$new_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $new_array[] = $row;
}
```

Or, if you want to key your array by a unique column (Primary key, for example):

```
$new_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $new_array[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. See code added at the end of the answer.

Comment: Also, if you get array(0), it could be because your query isn't returning any rows and/or your query is failing and you're not checking to see if you've got MySQL errors.

Comment: @user2511459 Where are you getting the send to variables from?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you almost got it. It's lower A in 'array'

To initialize an empty array:

```
$to = array();
```

In your case (you already have some values), you can do:

```
$to = array(
   $send_to1 => $value1,
   $send_to2=> $value2
);
```

In either case, you can later add more elements doing

```
$to[$someOtherKey] = $someOtherValue;
```